# Does ng-grid support virtual scrolling?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slickgrid, ng-grid

I wanted to use Slickgrid for the grid functionality in my app but since I am using AngularJS for the most part i thought that ng-grid is the way to go but not sure whether it supports virtual scrolling (I tried to look into their documentation and did not find any thing about virtual scrolling support). It would be great if some one could also enlighten me the pros and cons using ng-grid vs slick grid if possible.

Comment: By virtual scrolling do you mean not building the entire DOM (for many, many rows); Or, do you mean querying for more data when you are at the bottom of your current data set?

Comment: @DavinTryon yes, I meant not building the entire DOM and just building for the current user's view-port.

Comment: Then, yes, it supports both row and column virtualization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, ng-grid supports row virtualization.  You can see in the [grid configuration options](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options) that there is a setting for `virtualizationThreshold` that is set to 50 by default.