# Objects taking too long to display on view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, object, optimization, ng-grid

I am new to AngularJS. I am using ng-grid to display the search results from Web API. When I see the development tools, I can see that all the search results have been fetched but it takes longer to display on the view. Any optimization method to display those objects (Search result) quicker ? 
In this case, I do not know which specific piece of code I need to provide here, but I am using service to call the web api and service returns promise to the controller as a result.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How many rows/columns do you fetch?

Comment: For each search result, I can see in developer tools, all objects are fetched but after few seconds they are displayed on UI. As number of rows increased, the longer it takes to display.

Comment: Roughly how many rows do you have? If you have a million rows vs. 100 - it might make a difference

Comment: I have rows range from 50 up to 1200.

Comment: How many columns per row?

Comment: Can you also create a Fiddle? Just paste a sample data directly into an object.

Comment: There are 7 columns and those are fixed.

Comment: Hmm, up to 8,400 cells. Typically this is handled with paging.

Comment: Any alternative of paging? because it is requirement and don't want to use paging.

Comment: hmm... ng-grid does support [row virtualization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614589/does-ng-grid-support-virtual-scrolling)

Comment: You may want to consider using [ngReactGrid](https://github.com/josebalius/ngReactGrid/)

Comment: Here is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4EXUGfVGZQgbbJyv51v2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution after some research. 
Now I upgraded ng-grid to [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) which is updated version (Version 3 which is in BETA mode now) from Angular-UI developers. It's very optimized. Now I can search around 5000 results in 2 seconds.!

Thanks..